# Как установить межбуквенный интервал у TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

Обычный WPF TextBlock, никак не могу найти приличный способ установки межбуквенного интервала.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования - это привлечет больше внимания к вопросу.

Comment: Лучший вариант — использовать шрифт с нужными вам параметрами

Comment: Мне в конкретный стиль со всеми установленными параметрами, надо просто проставить указанный меж буквенный интервал

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878059/5045688

Comment: Да спасибо, то что искал. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Только там Padding надо ставить , а не Margin инача размер букв режется.

Comment: Будьте добры, оформите ответ: приведите пример кода и объясните, почему лучше использовать Padding. И потом примите его.